# Find all rows where start and end are 14 hours apart

Tags: mysql

Our table has start_time and end_time as unix epoch timestamps. I'd like to find all the rows where the end_time is exactly 14 hours (50400) greater than the start time.

```
SELECT * FROM `mrbs_entry` WHERE (`end_time`-`start_time`)==50400
```

This seems slightly off, and in fact doesn't work. I'm not sure what the proper terminology to search though.

Comment: WHERE (`end_time`-`start_time`)=50400 A single `=`

Comment: Use 1 equal sign, not two.

Comment: Yep, too used to other languages where double = is the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `==` for comparing the values, but `=`.
Or you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME` to format is as date and then `DATESUB` with `INTERVAL 14 HOUR`. So it's:

```
SELECT * FROM `mrbs_entry` 
WHERE DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(`end_time`), INTERVAL 14 HOUR) = FROM_UNIXTIME(`start_time`);
```